# The Timepicker Of Flatpickr is not disabling in Mobile

Tags: jquery, flatpickr

I am using the [Flatpickr](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr) and it is working fine in desktop but in mobile it is not working properly like the date format and also the disabled feature for the time picker.

**This dateFormat is not working in Mobile:**

```
limitFlatPicker.init( {
    minDate: new Date(),
    selector: '#form-field-form_field_date',
    dateFormat: 'd/m/Y' // this should now work with minDate
});
```

and I have disabled the time picker but I am not able the un-disable it:

```
jQuery('#form-field-select_location').change(function(){

 jQuery('#form-field-field_d280ad3').attr("disabled", "disabled");
 jQuery('#form-field-time_for_mobile').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    
     console.log( jQuery(this).val() );
     if(jQuery(this).val() == 'Northwest Indiana Mobile') {
    console.log('Northwest Indiana Mobile');
        jQuery('#form-field-time_for_mobile').removeAttr("disabled");
        jQuery("#form-field-time_for_mobile").attr("required", "true");
        jQuery("#form-field-field_d280ad3").removeAttr("required");
        jQuery('#form-field-field_d280ad3').val('');
    } else {
        console.log('Other');
        jQuery('#form-field-field_d280ad3').removeAttr("disabled");
        jQuery("#form-field-field_d280ad3").attr("required", "true");
        jQuery("#form-field-time_for_mobile").removeAttr("required");
        jQuery('#form-field-time_for_mobile').val('');
    } 
});
```

This code is not working for mobile: `jQuery('#form-field-field_d280ad3').removeAttr("disabled");`. At the first it is disabled but In mobile it is not un-disable and this is the `time picker`.

Any help is much appreciated.